# Lazy Load doesn't wait for click to load images that are above the fold

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading, jquery-lazyload

I am currently using Lazy Load on an image heavy webpage, and I don't want the images to load until I click a button. Lazy Load allows you to have event triggers like this, but I can only make it partially work.

Images below the fold wait for a click to appear, but anything above the fold is loaded when the page is initially brought up. Is this something that cannot be prevented, or am I doing something wrong?

Below is the code I am using.

```
<body>

  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.lazyload.js"></script>

  <img src="blank.gif" class="lazy" data-original="image.png" style="height: 500px; width: 500px;">

  <script>
     $("img.lazy").lazyload({
       event : "click",
       effect : "fadeIn"
     });
  </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, that the click event is not bound to an html element, e.g. a button. The plugin is not able to handle this out of the box.

So, I would use another plugin (e.g. [justlazy](http://fhopeman.github.io/justlazy/)), which is more suitable for your special use case.

```html
<body>

  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="justlazy.js"></script>
  
  <span data-src="default/image" data-alt="some alt text" title="some title"
      class="justlazy-placeholder">
  </span>

  <script>
    $("#someButton").click(function() {
      $(".justlazy-placeholder").each(function() {
        Justlazy.lazyLoad(this);
      });

      return false;
    });
  </script>

</body>
```

The demo page of the plugin provides a lot of examples.